# QLineEdit and Changing font for the “PlaceHolder” text

Tags: qt

Is there a stylesheet tag I can use to change the font/font size of the placeholder text (and just that, leave the normal edit text as is) in QLineEdit?

Answer (score 4):

The placeholder is shown only if `text()` is empty. Connect `textChanged` to your slot and set appropriate font using `setFont`. If `text()` is empty, set placeholder font, instead set normal font.